# Using a Texture as an Ambient map

Tags: three.js

I am looking to use a texture as an Ambient map in Three.JS - and am not sure hoe to implement this. Here is the code for my material so far:

```js
var shader      : THREE.Shader              = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
var uniforms    : THREE.Uniforms            = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

    uniforms[ "enableAO" ].value            = false;
    uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value       = true;
    uniforms[ "enableSpecular" ].value      = true;
    uniforms[ "enableReflection" ].value    = true;
    uniforms[ "enableDisplacement" ].value  = false;
    uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value             = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( this.earthMaterials.earthNormal );
    uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value            = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( this.earthMaterials.earthMap );
    uniforms[ "tSpecular" ].value           = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( this.earthMaterials.earthMap );
    uniforms[ "uNormalScale" ].value.set( this.earthMaterials.normalScale, this.earthMaterials.normalScale );
    uniforms[ "uDiffuseColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();
    uniforms[ "uSpecularColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();
    uniforms[ "uAmbientColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();


var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true, fog: false };
this.earthNormal = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );
```

How do I use a texture as an ambient map ?

Thank you for the help !

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Ah - sorry (how embarrassing)... edited my post... thank you ...

Comment: Do you mean ambient occlusion map? Show a live example of what you have working so far, and then ask a specific question about it.

Comment: .... to implement the Day/Night cycle on my GeoGlobe ( here : http://kurst.co.uk/samples/flightpaths/ ), I used a texture as an Ambient Map. So, when ambient light hits the globe it shows one texture ( night ), otherwise it shows the earth/day texture... am trying to implement something similar in three.js... hope this helps ... thanks again....

Comment: And this is a live example of my Three.Js implementation so far: http://kurst.co.uk/samples/threejs/tjsone/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to implement ambient occlusion.

You are already using the "normal" shader, and it supports an AO map. All you have to do is enable and assign your AO map.

An alternative is to bake the AO into your diffuse map.

A third option is to treat the AO map as a lightMap. `MeshPhongMaterial` supports light maps, it just doesn't support displacement maps, which you do not appear to be using anyway.

three.js r.58

Comment: Gave AO a go, not sure it's what I need. Trying to implement a day / night cycle on the globe: http://kurst.co.uk/samples/threejs/tjsone/ (threeJS version)... So when the light hits the globe it shows one map, and another on the dark side.. You can see it working here ( flash version):  http://kurst.co.uk/samples/flightpaths ... Thank you...